# How to create .NET2 compatible app in VS2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, versioning, portability

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and .NET4, but I would like to create application(Windows Form Application) that can be also run in .NET2. The reason is that I want it to be very easy to use and portable across many machines and not everybody has .NET4 installed.

Can I do it or do I need to install older version of Visual Studio? Is so what version is the best for most portable .NET app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify the target framework in the properties of the project:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can select which .NET Framework version you want to target when you create a new project.  If you want to change the framework of an existing project, do what Darin has illustrated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the target framework by looking at the propeties of the solution you are working on.

I would highly advise you to target .NET 3.5 just based on the age of .NET 2.0.

.NET Framework 2.0 was attached to Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: does most WindowXP have 3.5? from your experience.

Answer (score 0):

By modifying the target framework is the way, but if you are thinking of portable maybe what you need is some kind of native code that works in every and/or most windows version.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to delete redundant namespaces from your namespace list. For example LINQ...